# How can I find classes that annotated with Scala annotations?

Tags: scala, annotations

For Example :

```
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

class MyAnnotation extends StaticAnnotation

@MyAnnotation
class A{
    ............
}
```

The question is how can I scan classpath to find classes that annotated with `MyAnnotaion` without using Spring or org.Reflections module?